# Do you know the reason why we must use the article a instead of the in the following?

Tags: articles

> A human ear responds to a wide range of frequencies.

My teacher already has said me, when you are speaking about a part of your body that it belongs to it- it is not artificial et cetera- you must say the following:

the eye

the ear
 .
 .
 et cetera.

But, I just have seen the above sentence.

Would anybody kindly elaborate it?

Many thanks

Comment: You can use "a", "the", or no article at all. We have previous questions on the subject, e.g. the one I am closing this as a duplicate of. So your very premise is wrong. Just because the sentence uses "a" doesn't mean it *must* use "a" (as indeed your teacher has taught you). You might as well ask why the sentence must use "respond" or "range" or "human".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense of 'a human ear' puts the emphasis on the 'human' as adjective, as opposed to a different type of ear - eg, reptilian, or pteropine (bat-from the list [here])[1](http://www273.pair.com/med/words/animal_adjectives.htm).

The sense of 'the human ear' uses the definite article to refer to a specific item as indicative as the entire species, as in 'the lion is king of the beasts' - we have no specific lion in mind, it is the leonine species that is intended, but because it's easier to think of a single lion as being a king, the definite article is used.

It's less easy to think of a single human ear as symbolising the quality of human hearing, since they come in pairs, but using 'the' it's a way of referring to the hearing organ in general terms, rather than as distinct from other species' hearing faculties.

'Ear' is used here as a [Synechdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) - it is a part which stands for the entire human faculty of hearing.

Comment: So, which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both the definite and indefinite article can be used to make generic reference, that is, in the words of the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’, ‘when a noun phrase refers to the whole class, rather than just one or more instances of the class.’